# Lightning Component producing weird console.log

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

I built a lightning component that worked fine in both dev and qa. However, I can see that, things in QA are suddenly not fine. The code is exactly same in both the orgs, have verified this multiple times. Also, I am the system admin so it does not seem like a profile issue. The weird thing I found is the console.log output are entirely different in both the org. While dev displays a normal log in the console, the logs in QA are completely opposite and I don't understand why.

```
 checkAllBoxesSelection  : function(component,event){
 console.log(component);
.....more code
```

[image: console log in dev - NO Error]

[image: console log in QA]

Comment: Could be Locker Service? Is the critical update for it enabled in one org, and not the other?

Comment: @Aidan Thanks for the response. However, I just conformed that the LockerService is still not activated in the org. This is quite strange.

Comment: Yes, it is due to the Locker Service. You probably think to reorganize your in code, base on the Locker Service policies.

Comment: @DarkSkull Are you sure that LockerService would impact the code even if it is deactivated?

Comment: I'm pretty sure. I had a same issue some week ago.

Comment: @DarkSkull Could you please let me know what was the solution?

Comment: What would you print with console.log(). That is not an issue.  Tell me what you wanna print and I try to give you a solution.